# jQuery fade DIV content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I've been working on this scripts and  can't seem to get any help.

I have it on my fiddle. Basically I have some `div`s and I wanted them to fade in and fade out which they are doing right now correctly.

However, when content 1 is fading out, content 2 must be coming in at the same time, (I guess the opacity must be lighter) for the smoother transition.

Right now as content 1 fades out, it leaves a white spacing before Content 2 comes in.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function(){
     function fadeMyContent() {

         $(".thecontent:first").fadeIn(700).delay(1000).fadeOut(700,
             function() {    
                     $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());   
                     fadeMyContent();    
             });
      }
     fadeMyContent();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
     <li class='thecontent'> CONTENT 1</li>
     <li class='thecontent'> CONTENT 2</li>
     <li class='thecontent'> CONTENT 3</li>
     <li class='thecontent'> CONTENT 4</li>
<ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myislandshop/wV6Tk/5/

Comment: I applaud you on not using plugins! I think my worst niggle is when people say "I'd like [small feature  X]" and people suggest the entirety of jQuery UI. Overkill. Also, do you want those divs to crossfade, not fade in and out?

Comment: Yes plugins sometimes is too much for something small. Yes, cross fade will be cool but don't have to...

Comment: As a general rule, plugins are the way to go unless you're building something that nobody else has done. Why? Edge cases that you haven't thought of have been accounted for and the code is tested. The benefit *far* outweighs the few extra k.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work GUYS?: http://jsfiddle.net/myislandshop/wV6Tk/5/
Right now as content 1 fades out, it leaves a white spacing before Content 2 comes in. I DO NOT WANT THAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got you a solution. I'm using images in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/6xXf6/), but they're only to demonstrate the effect. Fading between black backgrounds is difficult; I suggest you give the `ul` a black background and fade the text/content above it in and out; it will give a nicer effect.

This is the code from the Fiddle. If you need an explanation, please ask.

```
function fadeDivs()
{
    var currentPanel = $("ul li:visible");
    var currentPanelIndex = currentPanel.index();

    currentPanel.fadeOut(1000);

    // If the next panel to fade in is beyond the last, start from the beginning again.
    if(currentPanelIndex == ($("ul li").length - 1))
    {
        $("ul li:first-child").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else    // If it's not the last li, keep going through the list
    {
        currentPanel.next().fadeIn(1000);
    }

    // Keep the ball rolling
    setTimeout(fadeDivs, 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Just to make it look nice - this can be deleted (it's just filler content)
    $("ul li:eq(0)").html("<img src='http://barbados.org/landscap/bcparadise1.jpg'>");
    $("ul li:eq(1)").html("<img src='http://www.get-free-wallpapers.com/wallpaper/previews/3652-1202425455/nature/oceans/3652-victoria-beach-laguna-beach-california.jpg'>");
    $("ul li:eq(2)").html("<img src='http://www.traveltovietnam.cc/Upload/Tour/2352008111155_SplendorOfMuiNeBeachMuiNe2.jpg'>");
    $("ul li:eq(3)").html("<img src='http://www.croatia-danexumag.com/cms_upload/upload/Apartments_VERUDELA_BEACH_00.jpg'>");

    // Start the ball rolling
    setTimeout(fadeDivs, 3000);
});
```

The images are licensed under blah blah who cares, bring on the lawsuit for me stealing your beach ;-)

Comment: lol stealing beach lol, im bringing my content in through XML or JSON...well JSON to be exact( but that does not matter ) but this looks good. Looking at it further.